# In Memory Data Cache for Performance in .Net Applications

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql, msmq

We have an application (rules engine) that has a lot of tables in memory to perform certain business rules. This engine is also used for writing back to the database when needed.

The DB structure is denormalized, and we have 5 transactional tables, that also sometimes need to be queried for reporting.

The issue here is, we want to cache the data inside the app, so it loads on App startup, and then only changes if the DB changed.

Any recommendations?

We are leaning towards creating a DB service, that will handle all Inserts, Updates and Deletes, and queue them to decrease load on the DB server (the transactional tables have loads of indexes also). Also, we are thinking of enabling the DB service to sit on top and serve all reports / other apps that need direct DB access.

The aim here ofcourse is to decrease DB hits for Select queries per request, and prioritize transactions. Also to ensure people accessing apps dont bring the DB server down.

Rules Engine is a C# desktop app, reporting and other apps are web based.

What would be the best way to go about this? I did also think of removing all indexes from my transactional table, and having a trigger insert into a new table which would be a copy, but indexed for report retrieval.

Comment: What's the problem you're trying to solve? What's the current performance pain point?

Comment: The paint points are:
1. Table Lock issues with too many writes / reads from the same table.
2. Data retrieval slow when checking rules per business transaction, the rules are based on other tables in the DB, so per  business transaction, this could mean 5 different select queries to 5 different table. Querying SQL server for the same tables is just a cost i want to avoid.
3. The data mentioned in #2 above may change, and polling / data cache expiry just don't seem "elegant"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should perhaps look at distributed caching solutions (from both performance and scalability point of view). In short, I am taking about scalable DB Services backed by distributed cache (so that multiple DB services get served by same cache).

Here's the [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd942840.aspx) that discusses distributed caching including various approaches for database synchronization. And here is the [blog](http://scottw.com/velocity) post that list few options in .NET for distributed caching.

Comment: Excellent - Distributed Cache - makes much more sense than having a Database service ... I will look into this.

Answer (score 1):

I've done something similar with an obscenely complex rules engine. Ultimately, I set it up so that the data was serialized centrally (with a process to release new changes, causing a new copy to be serialized and the blob stored somewhere accessible). During load, each app-server would check whether they have the up to date version of the blob, and if not fetch it (and store it locally).

Then all it has to do is deserialize the data into memory. No db hit, except for occasionally grabbing the new blob. It also means the app-server can work while the db server is offline (as long as it has a cached copy of the blob). It also polled periodically for new updates while running, of course - but only to the "is there a new blob" code (it still didn't need to hit the main tables).

Comment: That is a possibility, also by writing a timestamped file on table change, and possibly other ways, but the whole idea is not to poll at all. 

One approach could be, a trigger that writes a file with a time stamp, only load data when timestamp changed on the file. So for every table referenced by the rules engine, i just create a 0B file, and check the filename in the code to load changes, though that still isnt very elegant.

I was hoping SQL server or .net had some way of letting me know table values have changed. Caching really isnt the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You may be interested in [this article](http://www.15seconds.com/issue/010409.htm) It uses xml to store a readonly copy of the database (in memory). And XPath to query. Nowadays you'd prefer to query with linq, of course.

Comment: thanks - but this still doesn't help me determine how to change the dataset within the app (cached) when table values are changed. Caching the data is not the real problem, the problem is ensuring minimal select queries, but ensuring data is always the latest.